# Как добавить/удалить комментарий к многоугольнику?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты

Всем привет. Сделал по шаблону API. Добавил многоугольник. Как убрать отображение комментария (`name/description`) многоугольника при нажатии в нем мышкой. Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии ЛКМ карта увеличивалась.
[Пример](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/examples/mapstylepolygon.html) у яндекса, при нажатии на красную область появляется "Москва. Столицы России"

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы, читайте документацию коей в избытке и она на русском.

Код из примера:

```
 var plgn = new YMaps.Polygon([
            new YMaps.GeoPoint(x,y),
              ...
        ], {
            style: "polygon#Example",
            hasHint: 1,  //всплывающая подсказка
            hasBalloon: 0  //то что нужно 
        });
```

Про обработку кликов:

[Яндекс API](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/tasks/map-events.xml)